# Spring Data JPA doing update to perform simple query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, persistence, jpql

I'm using some attribute converter from JPA 2.1 to converter some fields and in this case to execute this

```
@NotNull
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "INVITEE_INFLUENCER_IND", nullable = false, length = 1, columnDefinition = "char")
    private Boolean inviteeInfluencer;
```

and the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface InvitationRepository extends JpaRepository<Invitation, Long> {
    List<Invitation> findByCustomerId(Long customerId);
}
```

Apparently is trying to update the entity and even worse without calling the attribute converter for that field which seems to result on this null arriving on the database.
Why during a query execution is calling for an update on the entity and also the attribute converter was not called yet.

```
InvitationIntTest.testCancelNextInvitations FAILED
    javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [xxxx.Invitation] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
    List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=inviteeInfluencer, rootBeanClass=class xxxx.Invitation, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1251)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1319)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:123)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:492)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy276.findByCustomerId(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening?

Comment: Apparently you have entities in your first level cache and those are, apparently dirty. Hence hibernate is doing a flush as to synchronize the in-memory state with the database to give you consistent query results.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes,
First I executed a save and flush
`final Invitation invitationSaved = invitationRepository.save(invitation);
        invitationRepository.flush();
        return invitationSaved;`

and I ensured that this field has been fulfilled on the convertToDatabaseColumn, also because is not null in the database. And subsequently when I call this method **findByCustomerId** when the data is been converted to the value waiting for that I'm receiving on convertToEntityAttribute null which is causing this

Comment: But I still didn't figure out why this value which I ensured that was saved and flushed, later on when I'm running the findByCustomerId query, is receiving null